# Keras custom loss function with arccos

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, loss-function

I am trying to build a custom loss function in Keras with **acos** insinde. the function is used to compare the similarity of two quaternions. 
is there a way to implement it using Keras backend? if not what is the alternative?

Comment: Have you looked at [`tf-quaternion`](https://github.com/PhilJd/tf-quaternion)?

Comment: thank you for your response. I have already checked it. I can do quaternion calculations with tensorflow with no problem but I have seen in many forums that i should use backend for the custom loss functions when using Keras. otherwise it would be complicate. is that true ?

Comment: Keras backend or low level tensorflow API. You would also probably have to use `tf-quaternion` since operations on quaternions differ from operations on regular tensors.

Comment: using low level tensorflow API solved my problem. thank you @Vlad

Comment: Great, glad to hear  !

Comment: @B.BGS Is it possible to share your loss function? I'm looking for a loss function to calculate the angular distance between quaternions, which could be related to what you were trying to solve.